# PHP, MYSQL --> SELECT * directly after INSERT INTO statement

Tags: php, mysqli

i want to insert some data in a table, and after that directly retrieve all data from that table. But strange thing is that I get an error when I do this.

So my questions is, is it possible to build a function which inserts some data via $_POST and after that directly retrieves all data from the table including the fresh new inserted $_POST data?

error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /mnt/webr/c3/76/54476376/htdocs/includes/functions.php on line 293 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /mnt/webr/c3/76/54476376/htdocs/includes/functions.php on line 293

```
/**********************************************************************************************************************************

2. Customer new ******************************************************************************************************************

***********************************************************************************************************************************/

function customer_new($user_name) {

    //DB settings
     include_once "config/config_fl.php" ;
           $query_insert = ("INSERT INTO customers (user_name               , 
                                                    customer_name               ,
                                                                              customer_legal_sort         ,
                                                                            customer_vat_applicable ,
                                                                            customer_payment_terms  ,
                                                                            customer_contactperson  ,
                                                                            customer_email          ,
                                                                            customer_telphone       ,
                                                                            customer_address_visit  ,
                                                                            customer_number_visit   ,
                                                                            customer_num_add_visit  ,
                                                                            customer_postal_visit   ,
                                                                            customer_city_visit     ,
                                                                            customer_country_visit  ,
                                                                            customer_visit_vs_post  ,
                                                                            customer_address_post     ,
                                                                            customer_number_post      ,
                                                                            customer_num_add_post       ,
                                                                            customer_postal_post    ,
                                                                            customer_city_post      ,
                                                                            customer_country_post   ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

          $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_insert);
          $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssissssssissss",  $user_name                        ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_name']           ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_legal_sort']     ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_vat_applicable'] ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_payment_terms']  ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_contactperson']  ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_email']          ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_telphone']       ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_address_visit']  ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_number_visit']   ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_num_add_visit']  ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_postal_visit']   ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_city_visit']     ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_country_visit']  ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_visit_vs_post']  ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_address_post']   ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_number_post']    ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_num_add_post']   ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_postal_post']    ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_city_post']      ,
                                                                            $_POST['customer_country_post']   );
          $stmt->execute();
          $stmt->store_result();
   }



/**********************************************************************************************************************************

3. Customer info ******************************************************************************************************************

***********************************************************************************************************************************/

function customer_info($user_name) {
  unset($mysqli);
  //DB settings
  include_once "config/config_fl.php" ;

  $query_select = ("SELECT * FROM customers where user_name = ? ");
  $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_select);
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_name);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->store_result();
  $count = $stmt->num_rows();

   $stmt->bind_result ($customer_number         ,
                       $user_name               , 
                       $customer_name               ,
                       $customer_legal_sort       ,
                       $customer_vat_applicable ,
                       $customer_payment_terms  ,
                       $customer_contactperson  ,
                       $customer_email          ,
                       $customer_telphone       ,
                       $customer_address_visit  ,
                       $customer_number_visit   ,
                       $customer_num_add_visit  ,
                       $customer_postal_visit   ,
                       $customer_city_visit     ,
                       $customer_country_visit  ,
                       $customer_visit_vs_post  ,
                       $customer_address_post     ,
                       $customer_number_post      ,
                       $customer_num_add_post       ,
                       $customer_postal_post    ,
                       $customer_city_post      ,
                       $customer_country_post   ); 


      $stmt->fetch();

    //  $customer_data=array();


      $customer_data = array ( 'customer_number'        =>$customer_number         ,
                               'user_name'              =>$user_name               , 
                               'customer_name'          =>$customer_name                 ,
                               'customer_legal_sort'    =>$customer_legal_sort       ,
                               'customer_vat_applicable'=>$customer_vat_applicable ,
                               'customer_payment_terms '=>$customer_payment_terms    ,
                               'customer_contactperson' =>$customer_contactperson  ,
                               'customer_email'         =>$customer_email          ,
                               'customer_telphone'      =>$customer_telphone         ,
                               'customer_address_visit' =>$customer_address_visit  ,
                               'customer_number_visit'  =>$customer_number_visit     ,
                               'customer_num_add_visit' =>$customer_num_add_visit    ,
                               'customer_postal_visit'  =>$customer_postal_visit   ,
                               'customer_city_visit'    =>$customer_city_visit     ,
                               'customer_country_visit' =>$customer_country_visit    ,
                               'customer_visit_vs_post' =>$customer_visit_vs_post    ,
                               'customer_address_post'  =>$customer_address_post     ,
                               'customer_number_post'   =>$customer_number_post    ,
                               'customer_num_add_post'  =>$customer_num_add_post     ,
                               'customer_postal_post'   =>$customer_postal_post    ,
                               'customer_city_post'     =>$customer_city_post      ,
                               'customer_country_post'  =>$customer_country_post   ); 

  $stmt->close();
  $mysqli->close();
  return $customer_data; 

}
```

Comment: perhaps update your question with the code you have tried and the errors you have received

Comment: Just do a header redirect to the same file having queried a SELECT.

Comment: Fred -ii-  do you mean a header RETURN from the INSERT statement function part?

Comment: On a successful insert/update, add a header after the query. Or, you can add a query select outside your functions to show existing data, while using a header on successful insert/update/delete which will then show the newly added post.

Comment: Doesnt worl: ation - headers already sent by (output started at (...)

Comment: You probably have an echo or HTML on top of your present code. If so, place that under your PHP/SQL, or try adding `<?php ob_start(); ?>` at the top of your pages. That sometimes works.

Comment: Also two functions doen`t work, then it says my MYSQLI variable isn`t set anymore at the select stamtent

Comment: @Fred-ii-, I don't get why he would need to redirect - if he has inserted the data into the table then it should be immediately available.

Comment: @Krooy_mans did you solve your error with the bind_param on line 287-8? Have you confirmed (via phpMyAdmin or otherwise) that the data actually is being inserted?

Comment: Yes, the table is updated continuosly. And strange this is that, when i just show the debiteuren.php page i get all data i want, but when i INSERT fist and then directly SELECT the SELECT statement fails

Comment: @PeterBowers I must've misunderstood the question then. That's the impression I got from reading their 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you can't execute more than one `mysqli_execute` without releasing the result of each of them. 
Maybe you should try, instead of `$stmt->close()` a `$stmt->free_result()` and see if that works.
Anyway, I suggest you to always print the mysqli error to see what isn't really working.

```
<?php
include_once "config/config_fl.php" ;
function customer_new($user_name) {
   global $mysqli;

    $query_insert = ("INSERT INTO customers (
                        user_name               , 
                        customer_name               ,
                        customer_legal_sort         ,
                        customer_vat_applicable ,
                        customer_payment_terms  ,
                        customer_contactperson  ,
                        customer_email          ,
                        customer_telphone       ,
                        customer_address_visit  ,
                        customer_number_visit   ,
                        customer_num_add_visit  ,
                        customer_postal_visit   ,
                        customer_city_visit     ,
                        customer_country_visit  ,
                        customer_visit_vs_post  ,
                        customer_address_post     ,
                        customer_number_post      ,
                        customer_num_add_post       ,
                        customer_postal_post    ,
                        customer_city_post      ,
                        customer_country_post   
                    ) VALUES (
                        ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
                    )"
    );

    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_insert);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssssssissssssissss",  $user_name                        ,
        $_POST['customer_name']           ,
        $_POST['customer_legal_sort']     ,
        $_POST['customer_vat_applicable'] ,
        $_POST['customer_payment_terms']  ,
        $_POST['customer_contactperson']  ,
        $_POST['customer_email']          ,
        $_POST['customer_telphone']       ,
        $_POST['customer_address_visit']  ,
        $_POST['customer_number_visit']   ,
        $_POST['customer_num_add_visit']  ,
        $_POST['customer_postal_visit']   ,
        $_POST['customer_city_visit']     ,
        $_POST['customer_country_visit']  ,
        $_POST['customer_visit_vs_post']  ,
        $_POST['customer_address_post']   ,
        $_POST['customer_number_post']    ,
        $_POST['customer_num_add_post']   ,
        $_POST['customer_postal_post']    ,
        $_POST['customer_city_post']      ,
        $_POST['customer_country_post']   );
    $stmt->execute();

    // You don't need to store result
    $stmt->free_result();
}

function customer_info($user_name) {
 global $mysqli;
//No sense of unsetting mysqli variable

$query_select = ("SELECT  customer_number, customer_name, customer_legal_sort, custom_var_applicable, ... FROM customers where user_name = ? ");
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query_select);
$stmt->bind_param("s", $user_name);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$count = $stmt->num_rows();

// You must specify what columns are you selecting to fetch them, or it won't work

$stmt->bind_result ($customer_number         ,
        $user_name               , 
        $customer_name               ,
        $customer_legal_sort       ,
        $customer_vat_applicable ,
        $customer_payment_terms  ,
        $customer_contactperson  ,
        $customer_email          ,
        $customer_telphone       ,
        $customer_address_visit  ,
        $customer_number_visit   ,
        $customer_num_add_visit  ,
        $customer_postal_visit   ,
        $customer_city_visit     ,
        $customer_country_visit  ,
        $customer_visit_vs_post  ,
        $customer_address_post     ,
        $customer_number_post      ,
        $customer_num_add_post       ,
        $customer_postal_post    ,
        $customer_city_post      ,
        $customer_country_post   ); 

while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $customer_data = array ( 
            'customer_number'        =>$customer_number         ,
            'user_name'              =>$user_name               , 
            'customer_name'          =>$customer_name                 ,
            'customer_legal_sort'    =>$customer_legal_sort       ,
            'customer_vat_applicable'=>$customer_vat_applicable ,
            'customer_payment_terms '=>$customer_payment_terms    ,
            'customer_contactperson' =>$customer_contactperson  ,
            'customer_email'         =>$customer_email          ,
            'customer_telphone'      =>$customer_telphone         ,
            'customer_address_visit' =>$customer_address_visit  ,
            'customer_number_visit'  =>$customer_number_visit     ,
            'customer_num_add_visit' =>$customer_num_add_visit    ,
            'customer_postal_visit'  =>$customer_postal_visit   ,
            'customer_city_visit'    =>$customer_city_visit     ,
            'customer_country_visit' =>$customer_country_visit    ,
            'customer_visit_vs_post' =>$customer_visit_vs_post    ,
            'customer_address_post'  =>$customer_address_post     ,
            'customer_number_post'   =>$customer_number_post    ,
            'customer_num_add_post'  =>$customer_num_add_post     ,
            'customer_postal_post'   =>$customer_postal_post    ,
            'customer_city_post'     =>$customer_city_post      ,
            'customer_country_post'  =>$customer_country_post   
    ); 
}
$stmt->free_result();
return $customer_data; 

}
```

You don't need to include your PHP file inside functions, you can only include it once at the beginning of the file, just remember to call the `$mysqli` variable as `global` (as you can see).
After insert query you were storing result, but it doesn't make any sense, because you don't need to get any data from the `SQL INSERT`, maybe just a number of inserted rows or just to check if the statement has done, but, each of these 2 scopes don't need to `store_result()`.

Another thing,in your `customer_info` function you're binding results from `SQL SELECT` which returns all columns from the Table. To use `bind_result()` functions, you need to specify which columuns are you going to need, so you will use a SELECT like this:

```
SELECT col1,col2,col3 FROM tablename WHERE col1=?
```

and then:

```
$stmt->bind_result(col1,col2,col3);
```

P.S: maybe you should try viewing the exactly `mysqli_error` which your statement is throwing, those `undefined` errors won't never help so much.
Just one last thing, you're executing lots of `mysqli` functions without checking anything, like if the `mysqli_execute` has worked or not, or anything similar. This could help you much more, instead of using all the functions like a chain

Comment: Thanks, but doesn`t work out: Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /mnt/webr/c3/76/54476376/htdocs/includes/functions.php on line 297 Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /mnt/webr/c3/76/54476376/htdocs/includes/functions.php on line 297

Comment: It`s so strange. It work when no update is triggered. But when i first insert a new row, and afterwards directly SELECT * then $MYSQLI doesn`t exist anymore. can you please have a look again? Many thanks in advance

Comment: In facts, mysqli close closes the connections, so your $mysqli variable won't be usable again. You should run that function when everything has finished

Comment: ok, I understand, but please see the original post, I now create two functions from where I left the close() function. But still $MYSQLI is gone

Comment: Thanks mate, the updated answer fixed it. The problem was related to the `Global $MYSQLI´ variable.. A very big thanks for your suppert here, and we´ve a working script here!    But....what`s the deal with the 'global' thing? I don`t understand why you can`t call it twice?

Comment: You should see variable scopes in the PHP documentation, but, I can briefly explan why you must use it twice: every time you create a function, you also create its variables, which can be used only inside of it. When your variable ($mysqli) is inside another PHP file (which obviously must be included) you should refer to that by using GLOBAL

Comment: Thanks CapitanFindus! You`ve made my day! Cheers, buy yourself a beer on me!

Answer (score 1):

to answer your question: yes, it is possible to first INSERT a row to a table and then retrieve it with SELECT. I think, your script fails because you close the mysql-connection after your INSERT.

A few more things to consider:

- to make sure you retrieve the inserted row (and you defined an autoincrement id in your table), you can use http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php to fetch those id after the INSERT
- having a few more error checks might be helpful. Here is an example: [PHP stmt prepare fails but there are no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882604/php-stmt-prepare-fails-but-there-are-no-errors/27883942#27883942)